# Javascript Clock - Clock is empty despite full program

Tags: javascript, date

I have poured over this code and I feel pretty positive about it. That being said, something is obviously missing, as the program itself comes up with an empty clock when run in the browser. I know that the brackets and parentheses all have a matching set, and I am fairly confident in my functions. The chrome developer tools were unhelpful. Anyone with a good eye for Javascript able to see what is missing here?

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hour = today.getHours();
  var min = today.getMinutes();
  var sec today.getSeconds();

  var ap = "AM";

  if (hour > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    ap = "PM";
  } else {
    switch (hour) {
      case 12:
        ap = "PM";
        break;
      case 0:
        ap = "AM";
        break;
    }
  }

  $("hours").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(hours);
  $("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(min);
  $("seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(sec);
  $("ap").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(ap);
};


var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  displayCurrentTime();
  setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <title>Clock</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
        <script src="clock.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <h1>Digital clock</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Clock</legend>
                <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
                <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
                <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
                <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
            </fieldset>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please post [mcve], which means *include the HTML*

Comment: In jQuery, in order to retrieve an element by its ID, you gotta add `#` before. Therefore it becomes `$("#hours").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(hours);`. Replicate that to the other ones and test it out. ;)

Comment: @AndréSilva added with no difference :( I don't believe we use # as a symbol to denote

Comment: @AndréSilva thats not `JQuery` he hijacked the `$` symbol

Comment: He is not using jQuery

Comment: @appleapple have added the HTML for reference

Comment: `The chrome developer tools were unhelpful.`  Are you getting any errors in your console?  Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code?

Comment: @Amy nothing is showing as an error--that's where I'm running into issues. The application, upon opening, is only supposed to show current time. There are no other steps or user input or print statements of any sort, which is why I am having trouble figuring out where the issue is.

Comment: @ShawnBenson not really possible, if you click the *run code snippet* in the question, you should get `Unexpected identifier` which also supposed to show up in the devtool console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a lot of (3) typos  ...

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};

var displayCurrentTime = function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hour = today.getHours();
  var min = today.getMinutes();
  var sec = today.getSeconds();

  var ap = "AM";

  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
    ap = "PM";
  } else {
    switch (hour) {
      case 12:
        ap = "PM";
        break;
      case 0:
        ap = "AM";
        break;
    }
  }

  $("hours").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(hour);
  $("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(min);
  $("seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(sec);
  $("ampm").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(ap);
};


var padSingleDigit = function(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  displayCurrentTime();
  setInterval(displayCurrentTime, 1000);
};
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Digital clock</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Clock</legend>
    <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>:
    <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>:
    <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
    <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span>
  </fieldset>
</main>
```

*there are other (non-functional) problems in this code, but since it is not the Q, I'd not change them to keep this answer on point.

Comment: @ShawnBenson it runs fine, do you click the *run code snippet* button in my answer? and as I write you have 3 typos.

Comment: I had missed one! It works--thank you. I am very new to this with an online class, so there are a lot of issues I'm just not used to seeing and picking out. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: @ShawnBenson you should try to use devtools (in chrome you press f12, or whatever the editor you like provide). It really helps.

Comment: Thank you! I had them brought up--but am still learning how to read them. Just silly user errors on my part. Thank you again!

Comment: @ShawnBenson other points may be opinion based, but there is one I'd strongly suggest: use `let` instead of `var` (unless you know what you're doing)

Comment: Is there a reason for the preference? This isn't something I've come across yet, so I am curious to know!

Comment: @ShawnBenson it's because `let` provides *better** scoping, for example the classic `for-var` problem, double declaration typo... see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more example. (**better*: it creates block scope, which is more common in other program afaik, and easier to use imho)

Comment: It would be helpful if you pointed out where the typos are. And questions about issues that are just a result of typos are off topic. :-) The logic around the switch and hour value is flawed.

Comment: @RobG I decided to not point exact typos out as a practice. And true, there are many other problems in this snip, but I don't think it's the point of this question. (But it's a valid point, answer updated include a warning, thanks)